# Getting the x,y location while using the UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `iphone simulator 3.2`. While I am placing the `UIScrollview` on the `Imageview`, the x, y coordinates aren't displayed in the console.

Please give me the solution to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(UIScrollView *)theScrollView.contentOffset`.  It’s a `CGPoint`.